# Eclipse variable substitution syntax rules?

Tags: eclipse, environment-variables

In many environments, variable substitution syntax provides for substituting or testing the final value of the variable. 
From bash ${foo#t*is}, for instance, is delete regex t*is in the variable.

Is there anything like this available in eclipse?

Specifically, the variables that the framework uses to control and invoke the underlying tools - the ones you see when you list system variables, environment variable, build environment variables, etc.

Accessing these for use in command line invocations is ${VARIABLE_NAME}, and there is a syntax for modifying them - I have seen ${PROJECT_NAME:MyProject} for example.

The question concerns the documentation and full capability of this ability.

Comment: Variables in what part of Eclipse? Eclipse is a huge tool which uses variables of some sort all over the place. What is supported varies a lot depending on the component.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I will clarify my question.

The variables that the framework uses to control and invoke the underlying tools - the ones you see when you list system variables, environment variable, build environment variables, etc.

Accessing these for use in command line invocations is ${VARIABLE_NAME}, and there is a syntax for modifying them - I have seen ${PROJECT_NAME:MyProject} for example.

The question concerns the documentation and full capability of this ability.